# CPU Dynamic voltage frequency scaling - does reducing both frequency and voltage always imply reduction in current?

Tags: voltage, power, current, vlsi, timing-analysis

Referring to the equation for dynamic power P=C·V<sup>2</sup>·f, is it always assumed that reducing voltage and frequency means a reduction in power and therefore current?

Example: let's assume for this argument C is held constant, the baseline calculation is P=100W, V=1.0V, and f=1GHz, then result C=0.1μF. From a voltage regulator perspective, V=1.0V would imply I=100A of current.

Now let's just change V=0.8V, f=0.8GHz, C=0.1μF, then the result is P=51.2W.

Is it that straightforward? With P nearly cut in half, can we assume the voltage regulator that supplies this P=51.2W, V=0.8V, therefore I=64A?

Comment: You refer to dynamic voltage and frequency scaling used in CPUs. The question is unclear to me.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The question is if the math example provided makes sense and seems representative of an example where scaling down voltage/frequency results in the power estimate provided.

Comment: I recommend to explain this context in the question because without that, a reader thinks "who would ever feed 100 nF with 1 GHz?", and the abbreviation DVFS is not common to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

That's somewhat correct. However, that doesn't mean you can scale down the *operational voltage* to any value for a given *clock frequency of operation* and save power. There are constraints.

Let us say, your chip is working at [\$1 \text{ GHz}\$, \$1.0\text{V}\$] at typical PVT conditions. You can save *dynamic power* (\$P_d = CV^2f.\alpha)\$ by sacrificing a little throughput (performance) by scaling the frequency down to \$800 \text{ MHz}\$. The idea here is that, a chip which is designed to operate at \$1 \text{ GHz}\$, will also function without failure at \$800 \text{ MHz}\$ for the same *operational voltage* as well.

Since the clock frequency is scaled down to \$800 \text{ MHz}\$, you can now afford to have larger data path delays inside the chip between flip-flops and all, as the timing paths are relaxed with larger window available for setup timing closure.

This leads to the implication that *operational voltage* can be reduced to **some margin**, which increases the delays inside, **and yet** operate the chip without any functional failure.

[image]
*\$\scriptsize{\text{[source: "STA for Nanometer Designs"]}}\$*

Now, how big/small this margin can be is something that's already proven during chip design. The chip would be fabricated after verifying timing at [worst/best-case PVT corners](https://asic-soc.blogspot.com/2008/03/process-variations-and-static-timing.html), which dictate the min/max *operating voltage* *and* *temperature* **for the given *frequency of operation***, which now becomes the chip's *operating specifications*.

> Is it that straightforward?

So, if you assume \$C\$ is constant, and **if you are within** the margins of *operational voltage* as defined by the chip's specifications for the clock frequency you target, the idea of scaling and *dynamic power* reduction is straight forward as in \$P_d \propto V^2f\$.

Also, since *operational voltage* is scaled, this leads to some amount of *static/leakage power* reduction as well.    Since the sum of *static* and *dynamic* *power* consumption is \$\approx\$ total power consumption,  you may not be able to come up with a linear relation with current like you have shown, because we don't know their individual contributions. However, yea the current reduces.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think you covered all my questions/concerns with your post. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer as solution if it solved your queries.  So that it would be helpful to others in future as well. @user318904